# Connect to ADB without confirming the box(Usb debugging is enable)

Tags: adb, 5.0-lollipop, usb, usb-debugging, broken-screen

I have an Android with a broken screen and I want to access the Android without ADB check to see the Android screen in Windows.

(USB debugging is already active and the problem is only in confirming the box)

Phone : J1 Ace

Android : 5.1.1

[image: picture from Vysor]

[image]

Comment: That authorization dialog is a security feature to prevent an unauthorized person from accessing sensitive user data or installing malware into the device. You cannot bypass it. However, if OTG mode is enabled and working you could try a USB hub (1 outlet, 2 or more inlet) where one inlet is connected to a mouse and the other one to the PC. See if that arrangement works out. Using mouse you can click on OK on that dialog.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Looks like you have found a similar question on [How to enable Android USB Debugging option without the "Allow USB Debugging" popup?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/185724/44325), though it is yet unanswered

Comment: you tagged the question with lollipop, so there is most likely a way to by-pass that by flashing modified boot.img

Comment: edit question and add phone info, such as model, android version, bootloader lock state

Comment: Just for the note: I checked, adb over wifi is not available in 5.0

Comment: @andrew-t Thank you, my Usb Debugging is enable, my problem is popup confirmation dialog

Comment: download ROM from samfw according to your region/carrier, extract boot.img, modify default.prop, repack boot.img into tar file and flash with older version of Odin3